# How to adjust online regex to be used in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

In React project, I want to pass as a prop `regex` for everything apart from empty space line:

```
const sharedSettings = {
type: 'text',
minLength: 1,
maxLength: 20,
required: true,
placeholder: 'Your name...',
pattern: /.*S.*/,
msg: 'Please enter your name',
};
```

But it's not working. I tried doing:

```
pattern: \/.*S.*\/
pattern: '//.*S.*//'
```

It didn't work. I tried testing `regex` online and it was fine. What kind of adjustments are needed?

Comment: Give us same sample strings that should match and not match your intended pattern. Your regex as written will match any string that has a capital S in it, at any position at all (you could re-write it as simply `/S/`). Doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Comment: It should match any string that is not made out of empty space. I tested it out on this site: https://regexr.com/ and it worked fine, but once I transfered it to JS file, I ran into problem. It started failing on any string.

Comment: `/^\s+$/` will match any string composed only of whitespace.

Comment: I tried that one as well, it doesn't work in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string containing at least one non-whitespace is simply `".*?[^\s].*"`.
Note that the ***pattern***  requires a whole line match. So a little `.*` before and after is needed.
Note that `".*?\S.*"` works just as well, since `\S` is shorthand for `[^\s]`.

Try it out ...

```html
<h1>The input pattern attribute</h1>

<form>
  <div>
    <label for="uname">Choose a username: </label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="name" required size="45"
           pattern=".*?[^\s].*">
    <span class="validity"></span>
    <p>Usernames must not be all whitespace.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Safari 10 (or earlier).</p>
```

Comment: I tried using it as `pattern: /\S/` but it was failing on any word. I tried writing it as a string but my prettier kept erasing one slash, leaving it as `pattern: '/S/'`, so I escaped it as `pattern: '/\\S/'`. But that, unfortunately didn't work either.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I'm using it with `HTML5` `input` verification. It results in: `<input pattern='/\S/' />`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp So try `pattern = ".*\S.*"` or `pattern = ".*\\S.*"` or `pattern = "\\S"`, etc ...

Comment: I found something that seems to work. `pattern=".*?[^\s].*"`, check it out.